# DotPeek debug using attach to process, without source code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dotpeek

I am currenlty trying to debug a service, but don't have the code located on the server, since there is alot and moving is not easy.

we are currently having issue with one server, and the only way I can debug the issue is by using dotpeek to decompile the .dlls and shown [here](https://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/) @IgalTabachnik

Problem with this is the last step, my breakpoint gives an error and says that sourcecode is not availbale? which i don't get? ... it should be available through dotpeek?

Another things that might be an issue, is that I am debugging a schdule task, and I am not able to attach to a process while starting at the same time.

Comment: do you need to use dotPeek or are you open to other tools that might do the job?

Comment: I am open for other tools that can do the job.. @PawełŁukasik

Comment: @famle, please submit a support request here https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/#.

Answer (score 4):

If you're having problems with dotPeek + symbol server, I do recommend using [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy). To do that you need to:

1. Open dnSpy as an administrator (dnspy-x86.exe or dnspy.exe depending on the target platform)
2. Load .exe file that contains the code of the service into dnSpy via File->Open
3. Navigate to the code where you want to put your breakpoint and set it there.
4. Go to Debug-Attach to process. Since you run dnSpy as an Administrator you should see your service on the list.
5. Select and attach to the process
6. Trigger the breakpoint.
7. debug

dnSpy generates it's own source code and has debugging capabilities so you can do everything in it. Its debugging experience is similar to Visual Studio's but it is not as reach as you can get in VS. Still, it can do its job.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? that dnSpy does not support 4.7.1? It does

Comment: No... Our server doesn't have .NEt 4.7.1, thus I am not able to run it... could it be recompiled to a older version such as 4.6?

Comment: Older version were using .net 4/.net 4.6 but not sure if you can find it somewhere. You can always get an older version of the repository and compile it yourself.

Comment: Hmm... Which commit should i clone then? @PawelLukasik

Comment: [this commit](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/commit/ccf6cc1046b2583cb45594e87f32b9ad215ea493#diff-a13f510bc9f2f660db5db50117ca7b0d) converts to 4.7.1 - so at least one before